# Is it possible to take a reusable system image in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, system-restore

I am looking for a consistent solution to setup several windows 10 tablets with the same exact software and system configuration without applying all the modifications (edit the registry, install software etc) manually.

I did the same with Linux, by taking an image of the filesystem but on Windows I'm struggling with native backup tools which fail in every possible way.

Is there a tool that would help me create a reusable customized windows 10 image?

Comment: Complete one tablet just the way you like it, then use DISM to make the image and deploy it....https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/capture-and-apply-windows-system-and-recovery-partitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Microsoft way" to do it would be setting up and using Microsoft deployed toolkit or MDT. This is free but kinda complex.

If you do some searching for MDT alternatives there are several out there. For our purposes we found just scripting everything was easier, and we didn't have golden images to maintain and update etc.

Comment: Will try the MDT way (never heard of it, thanks!) and see how it goes, powershell scripting sounds like a decent plan B